# Materialize CSS : Dropdown don't display properly inside collection

Tags: php, css, materialize

I am using materialize css. In which i created a collection. I want to display update and delete option. All things working. One small ui error is there that dropdown is clip inside collection item.

It may because of collection overflow hidden rule.

Can i change it without changing css overflow hidden?

Here is my code and screenshot of it.

```
<ul class="collection" id="products">
                    <?php
                         while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                         {

                    ?>
                            <ul id='dropdown<?php echo $row["id"]?>' class='dropdown-content'>
                                <li><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">Update</a></li>
                                <li><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <li class="collection-item avatar" style="opacity: 0">
                                <span class="title"><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <p><?php echo $row["description"] ?></p>
                                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content dropdown-button" data-activates='dropdown<?php echo $row["id"]?>'><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a>
                                <!-- <td style="width: 15%"></td>
                                <td style="width: 50%"></td>
                                <td style="width: 15%"><?php //echo $row["unit_id"] ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 10%"></td>
                                <td style="width: 10%"></td> -->
                            </li>
                    <?php
                         }
                    ?>
                    </ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just set the min-height of collection so its display properly on the screen.

```
<li class="collection-item avatar" style="opacity: 0;min-height: 17%">
                                <span class="title"><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <p><?php echo $row["description"] ?></p>
                                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content dropdown-button" data-activates='dropdown<?php echo $row["id"]?>'><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a>
                            </li>
```